# How do I join two documents by id

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5

I need some help with elasticsearch
I want to join two things the schema for the first thing looks like

STAT GROUP

```
{
    "_id": 38282922829,
    "statValues": [{
          _ref: 282828290,
     }]
}
```

STAT DATA

```
{
    "_id": 282828290,
    "key": itemsGained
}
```

As you can see, I want to join all the refs in statvalues with the id for the stat data. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) operator and [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html) operator to do this.

```js
db.STAT_GROUP.aggregate([
  {
     $unwind: '$statValues'
  },
  {
     $lookup: {
       from: 'STAT_DATA',
       localField: 'statValues._ref',
       foreignField: '_id',
       as: 'Refs'
     }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayGroundLink](https://mongoplayground.net/p/oqQt5Hdc2Ln)